# List all folder names in a text file

Tags: batch-file, directory, text-files

Im writing a batch to go through the current directory and list all the folder names in a text file.  what i have so far only lists file names. can somebody show me what im doing wrong?

```
@echo ON
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%# in (Just Processed*) do (
echo "%%~n#">>text.txt
)
Pause&Exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alright, i figured out what i was doing wrong.  at some point during my research i forgot to remove a part of the code that didnt work.  this is the working code.

```
@echo ON
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
For /D %%# in (*.*) do (
echo "%%~n#">>text.txt
)
Pause&Exit
```

Answer (score 3):

dir /ad /b /s >"folderlist.txt"

If you want the current directory only then remove the /s